# Comparing items in two lists

Tags: scala

I have two lists : `List(1,1,1) , List(1,0,1)`

I want to get the following :

1. A count of every element that contains a 1 in first list and a 0 in the corresponding list at same position and vice versa.
   In above example this would be 1 , 0 since the first list contains a 1 at middle position and second list contains a 0 at same position (middle).
2. A count of every element where 1 is in first list and 1 is also in second list.
   In above example this is two since there are two 1's in each corresponding list. I can get this using the intersect method of class List.

I am just looking an answer to point 1 above. I could use an iterative a approach to count the items but is there a more functional method ?
Here is the entire code :

```
class Similarity {
  def getSimilarity(number1: List[Int], number2: List[Int]) = {
    val num: List[Int] = number1.intersect(number2)
    println("P is " + num.length)
  }
}

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val s = new Similarity
    s.getSimilarity(List(1, 1, 1), List(1, 0, 1))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the first one:

```
scala> val a = List(1,1,1)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1)

scala> val b = List(1,0,1)
b: List[Int] = List(1, 0, 1)

scala> a.zip(b).filter(x => x._1==1 && x._2==0).size
res7: Int = 1
```

For the second:

```
scala> a.zip(b).filter(x => x._1==1 && x._2==1).size
res7: Int = 2
```

Comment: Couldn't you just say `x => x._1==1 && x._2==0` ?

Comment: Actually you can replace `filter(predicate).size` with just `count(predicate)`

Answer (score 8):

You can count all combinations easily and have it in a map with

```
def getSimilarity(number1 : List[Int] , number2 : List[Int]) = {

  //sorry for the 1-liner, explanation follows 
  val countMap = (number1 zip number2) groupBy (identity) mapValues {_.length}

}

/*
 * Example
 * number1 = List(1,1,0,1,0,0,1)
 * number2 = List(0,1,1,1,0,1,1)
 * 
 * countMap = Map((1,0) -> 1, (1,1) -> 3, (0,1) -> 2, (0,0) -> 1)
 */
```

---

The trick is a common one

```
// zip the elements pairwise

(number1 zip number2) 

/* List((1,0), (1,1), (0,1), (1,1), (0,0), (0,1), (1,1))
 *
 * then group together with the identity function, so pairs
 * with the same elements are grouped together and the key is the pair itself
 */ 

.groupBy(identity) 

/* Map( (1,0) -> List((1,0)), 
 *      (1,1) -> List((1,1), (1,1), (1,1)), 
 *      (0,1) -> List((0,1), (0,1)), 
 *      (0,0) -> List((0,0))
 * )
 *
 * finally you count the pairs mapping the values to the length of each list
 */

.mapValues(_.length)

/* Map( (1,0) -> 1, 
 *      (1,1) -> 3, 
 *      (0,1) -> 2, 
 *      (0,0) -> 1
 * )
```

Then all you need to do is lookup on the map

Answer (score 2):

Almost the same solution that was proposed by Jatin, except that you can use`List.count`for a better lisibility:

```
def getSimilarity(l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int]) =
  l1.zip(l2).count({case (x,y) => x != y})
```

Comment: Why not just `l1.zip(l2).count{case (x,y) => x != y}`

Comment: Because I didn't thought to use `count` when I wrote it first. I'm updating the answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
a.zip(b).filter(x => x._1 != x._2).size
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use foldLeft. Assuming there are no non-negative numbers:

```
a.zip(b).foldLeft(0)( (x,y) => if (y._1 + y._2 == 1) x + 1 else x )
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You could `zip` 2 lists to get list of `(Int, Int)`, collect only pairs `(1, 0)` and `(0, 1)`, replace `(1, 0)` with `1` and `(0, 1)` with `-1` and get sum. If count of `(1, 0)` and count of `(0, 1)` are the same the `sum` would be equal `0`:

```
val (l1, l2) = (List(1,1,1) , List(1,0,1))

(l1 zip l2).collect{
  case (1, 0) => 1
  case (0, 1) => -1
}.sum == 0
```

You could use `view` method to prevent creation intermediate collections.

2) You could use `filter` and `length` to get count of elements with some condition:

```
(l1 zip l2).filter{ _ == (1, 1) }.length
(l1 zip l2).collect{ case (1, 1) => () }.length
```